# нужно посчитать нарастающий итог без использования оконных функций

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не могу понять как сложить строки с одинаковым id, тем более нарастающий итог, и к тому же без оконной функции

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. Выложите пример данных как форматированные текстовые CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Покажите требуемый результат для показанных данных.

Comment: Обычный подход - использование двух копий таблицы, связанных по `t1.date <= t2.date`.

Comment: все равно не очень понял как мне посчитать нарастающий итог. через копию таблицы понял. а как сложить paid - нет

Comment: Делайте нормальные исходные - покажу. Я конвертировать фотографию в код не буду...

Comment: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_running_totals.html